# http response headerのserverをnginxから変えたい

Tags: nginx

nginxのバージョン情報などはconfファイルで設定できますが、
そもそもnginxという表記を別の文字列にしたい場合はどうしたらよいのでしょうか。

目的としてはnginxを使っていることを隠すためで、
理由はセキュリティ面ではなく、サービスを人に見せた時に「nginx使ってるんですね-」っていう人がちょっとうざいからです。
結構見たがる人っていますよね。

なのでいたずらとして「server: fuck」みたいな文字列に変えて遊んでみたいです。

Answer (score 1):

次の設定を `server{}`の中に書きます。

```
more_set_headers "Server: fukuoka";
```

するとレスポンスヘッダが次のようになります。

```
  Date: Fri, 18 Dec 2015 19:07:22 GMT
  Content-Type: text/html
  Content-Length: 233
  Connection: keep-alive
  Server: fukuoka
```